# Getting Google Maps Intent to Return Location

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

So I am trying to build an app that would allows the user to select a particular place from a Google Maps intent, and when the user pick a place, the intent would finish and return the latitude and longitude data to the previous activity.

What is the best way to do this?

What I have done so far:

I used GPSTracker from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/).

to get the current latitude and longitude, and then used these data to start a google map intent pointing to current location.

Comment: Hi, Jackyef, have you figured out how to do this? I am looking for a solution like what you had described above, wanted to know if you have got any solution to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website you posted in your question does not look like it contains the actual map. If you need assistance with adding a Google Map to your application I would start [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/).

Assuming you have that working and your code allows a user to place his or her point already, you can retrieve the coordinates of that point by using a built in function in the Marker class [getPosition()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#getPosition()).

You can use the coordinates by accessing the public variables .latitude and .longitude as follows:
`LatLng coord = myMarker.getPosition();`
`double latitude = coord.latitude;`
`double longitude = coord.longitude;`